# predictive text bobble effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to find a jquery plugin to simulate that bobble effect seen when we add tags to our stackoverflow questions. Similar to selecting multiple e-mail recipients on a an g-mail message. Any ideas ?

Comment: That is called autocomplete. For instance: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the plugin [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). It has autocomplete and tag features.

Another options are [Tagit](http://webspirited.com/tagit/) and [Tags Manager](http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager).